# How can I create a 3.3 V power rail from a 5 V power rail

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to create a 3.3 V power rail from a 5 V existing rail and have come up with the following schematic.

Can anyone see any issue with this implementation, also am i good to just connect Epad directly to ground. I assume the Cin capacitor is for decoupling but am not sure what its value should be.

Any suggestions for improvement.

[NCP114 Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp114-d.pdf)

Datasheet typical application:

[image: Datasheet]

Proposed circuit:

[image: Proposed]

Comment: Literally explained under the title "Input Capacitor Selection (CIN)" on page 13 of the datasheet you link to!

Comment: @MarcusMüller well thats embarrasing!

Comment: happens :) Don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume the Cin capacitor is for decoupling but am not sure what its value should be.

The datasheet says:

> 1 uF Ceramic X5R
> or X7R capacitor

At a high level, the capacitor provides power supply decoupling, making the 5V at the input pin more stable and smoother. While the regulator is intended to operate with a varying input voltage, smoothing it is still important for good performance.

The datasheet which you linked says:

> A small capacitor is needed from this pin to ground to assure stability

which is a pretty good reason - without the capacitor, the regulator could fail to regulate, start oscillating, etc.

One (handwavy) way to look at this:

- The 5V power supply line/rail has resistance and inductance upstream of the regulator.
- If the current demand on the 3.3v rail changes abruptly (because of the load's behavior), the current demand on the 5V rail will change abruptly as well. The inductance and resistance of the 5V rail would cause the voltage on the 5V rail to change abruptly as a result
- A capacitor of the appropriate size will source and sink abrupt current demands, keeping the 5V voltage at the input pin stable.

This matches further remarks in the datasheet:

> This capacitor will provide a low impedance path for
> unwanted AC signals or noise modulated onto constant
> input voltage

and further

> A good input
> capacitor will limit the influence of input trace inductance
> and source resistance during sudden load current changes.
> Larger input capacitor may be necessary if fast and large
> load transients are encountered in the application.

A full mathematical discussion of *why* the input capacitor makes the regulator stable would require some control theory and analysis of the control loop.